# Political and Controversial Discussions in the Chat Rooms

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I've been looking through many of the recent discussions in the [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3819/jaamiat-stackexchange-al-islamy). Many have been regarding political and controversial topics such as the current situation in Iraq, Syria, ISIS, Palestine, etc.

I believe that these should not be allowed on this site.

The purpose of this site is to ask and answer questions about the religion of Islam. Its here to create a large base of credible Islamic knowledge.

**We are not here to discuss politics. We are not here to make people feel uncomfortable. We are not here to put others down.**

That said, I don't see that happening throughout the site, and specifically in the chatroom. As a community, we need to work to stop this behavior.

Comment: But Islam is full of politics. The prophet (pbuh) had his own politic for guiding muslim society.

Answer (score 7):

Although I agree with the points Daniel made, I also agree that lenghty conversations about politics in main chat room can be annoying. Not everyone in the main chat room (for example myself) is interested in politics and discussing politics in lenght on main chat room might discourage those users from participating in main chat room.

I think people who would like to discuss politics might open another room to discuss topics that they mutually are interesed in. That way, others don't have to read through those discussions while they were hoping to socialize with fellow Muslims in main chatroom.

Comment: +1 for the good solution.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the chatrooms are considered to be more informal areas for discussion of whatever the current occupants are interested in discussing. If that happens to be politics, I don't think there is any issue with that. In other words, the rules of on-topicness are not really relevant to the chatroom. If it comes to the point of harassment, that is certainly a problem. People have been (properly) banned from chatting in the past because of harassment and intentionally instigating fights. As long as that system continues to work, I don't think there is really any issue.

Comment: +1, but still it seems like some are misusing the site to advertise their own group, posting twitter accounts and copy pasting declarations.

Comment: I agree you somewhat @Daniel, since in general, chatrooms are counted to be more informal area... (and at least there ought to be a section (in this site) to discuss concerning the issues which have some limitation in meta section. Of course I agree to you (dear Bludream) that occasionally misusing... (but I believe there must be a more free section to..). Good luck both of you mates.