# Why ISIS related discussion is not allowed in Chat?

Tags: discussion, chat, politics

As you enter the main Islam chat, you find the banner "ISIS related discussion not allowed", [although we have a policy](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1213/4841) that political discussions in chat are to be allowed. Yet the mod chooses to enforce this constraint which is problematic.  Also ISIS related issues can be handled in a high quality academic manner as we [can see here](http://www.ghuraba.info/en/ybahrumi/refuting-the-groups-of-division/). Hence I find no reason to ban discussion and questions related to ISIS in at least chat.

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason politics needs to be off-topic in chat.  The problem is, some users were unwilling and/or unable to discuss that particular topic reasonably and professionally, and despite *multiple warnings* I still needed to flag and suspend *multiple users* for behaving non-constructively while discussing it.

It was not conducive to maintaining a civil environment in the chatroom, I had *yet* to see *any* actual value come forth whenever the topic was brought up, and I was quite frankly sick of dealing with it.  So I called a moratorium on the topic entirely in the main chat room.

If you want to discuss it, just open a new chat room and talk about it there; there's really nothing stopping you.  But if the discussions continue to devolve into unprofessional behaviour and attacks, there will just end up being further suspensions involved.